# How to make an array for every object within an array?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I have a code that picks out items from a list, and I have a scanner go through the file (which has movies and then actors per each line) and add movies to an array.  How would I make it so that every single movie it adds to the arraylist also stores the actors that come after it on the line?  For example: 
one line would be Movie Name (Date)/LastName, FirstName/Lastname2, Firstname2/ and so on for each line.  My code includes a class Movie which turns the Movie Name into a string.  How would I be able to at any given point search for any movie and have it pull up all the actors that starred in it?

```
 public void loadDataFromFile(String fileName){
    /**
     * This method takes in one parameter, a file name, and prints out the data from that file
     */
    Scanner theScanner3 = null;
    myMovies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        try{    
         theScanner3 = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName));}

        catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + ex.getMessage());
            }

        while( theScanner3.hasNextLine()){
        int i = 1;
        i = i+1;
            Movie foo = new Movie(theScanner3.nextLine());
            myMovies.add(foo);

        }
        theScanner3.close();
        }
```

I need to be able to search for a movie's name and have it return to me every actor on the same line as that movie.  However, I have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting myMovies as an ArrayList, you want to set it as a Map.
But before that, you want to create a separate ArrayList consisting of the actors for that movie.
So it will be:

```
ArrayList<String> actors = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then:

```
Map<Movie, ArrayList<String>> myMovies = new HashMap<Movie, ArrayList<String>>();
```

You want to create myMovies before reading in all the lines and perhaps even set it as a global variable if you want to access it at anytime.
In order to get all the actors for that specific movie, you would do the following:

```
ArrayList<String> movieActors = myMovies.get([movie_object]);
String firstActor = movieActors.get(0);
```

For example:

```
Map<Movie, ArrayList<String>> myMovies = new HashMap<Movie, ArrayList<String>>();
...
while(theScanner3.hasNextLine()) {
    int i = 1;
    i += 1
    ArrayList<String> actors = new ArrayList<String>();
    //
    //do some splits using delimiters to separate out name of the movie and actors
    //for example, let's say the strings are in an array called 'split'
    //where split[0] is the movie title
    //and everything that follows afterwards are the actor names
    //
    String movieName = split[0]
    for(int j = 1; j < split.length; j++) {
        actors.add(split[j]);
    }
    //creating the objects
    Movies foo = new Movie(movieName);
    //now to store the movie and the arraylist of actors into myMovies
    myMovies.put(foo, actors);
    ...
```

Another way of achieving this would be to have the actor names inside the Movie object. So that you can just call create and call a get method of that certain movie which can return a list of actors' names.

Answer (score 0):

### The best way of doing this would be using a Map.

It establishes a relation between keys (movies in this case) and values (lists of actors in this case).

Consider it as a collection of actors classified (grouped) by movies.

**Declaration:**

```
Map<Movie, List<Actor>> actorsByMovies = new HashMap<>();
```

---

**Add movie:**

```
Movie newMovie = ...
actorsByMovies.put(newMovie, new ArrayList<>());
```

---

**Get actors from movie:**

```
Movie myMovie = ...
List<Actor> actors = actorsByMovies.get(myMovie);
```

---

**Get all movies:**

```
Set<Movie> allMovies = actorsByMovies.keySet();
```

---

**Check for a movie:**

```
Movie myMovie = ...
boolean doesMovieExist = actorsByMovies.containsKey(myMovie);
```

---

Here is further [**reference**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Like where would I place these- would I have to modify them from the form they are in above?  Would I place them in the movie class or the main code?

Comment: None of these would be in movie class. They will be in your main code only. Especially declaration and adding movies will be in `loadDataFromFile` method which should return the map. Others are useful if and when you need them.

Comment: Consider it as a collection of actors classified (grouped) by movies.

Comment: Well I put the declaration you put up there in load data from file., but I still don't know how to get actors from a specific movie.  I don't know what I am supposed to replace the ... with to get the code below to return all the actors.

Comment: e.g. `Movie myMovie = actorsByMovies.keySet().toArray()[3];`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Movie` class could store all the information you want to keep about each movie. That could include a list of all actors in the movie. It could also include a way of creating a movie from a scanner:

```
class Movie {
    private final String name;
    private final Person director;
    private final List<Person> actors;
    private final int yearOfRelease;

    public Movie makeFromScanner(Scanner movieScanner) {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.yearOfRelease = movieScanner.nextInt();
        ...
        return movie.
    }

    public boolean hasActor(Person actor) {
        return actors.contains(actor);
    }
}
```

If you store your list of movies as a list:

```
List<Movie> movies;
```

Then finding, for example, all movies with a particular actor would be:

```
Set<Person> moviesWithActor = movies.stream()
    .filter(movie -> movies.hasActor(myActor))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or finding all actors for a movie:

```
Set<Person> actorsForMovie = movies.stream()
    .filter(movie -> movie.hasName(myMovie))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

While it would obviously be more efficient to have something like a `Map` to find the movie by name quickly, unless you have millions of movies or are searching many times per second it is not necessary: an exhaustive search is fine.